# get rid of subsubsection in paragraph reference

Tags: cross-referencing, paragraphs, revtex

In a `revtex4` document I have: a section (arabic), a subsection (letter) and a paragraph (roman). I do not have any subsubsection.

I use the command `\label` to refer to the paragraph. When in the text I use the command `\ref` to refer to the paragraph I get something that looks like: "1A0I". "1" refers to section, "A" to subsection, "0" to subsubsection (that I do not have) and "I" (roman) to paragraph.

How can I drop the subsubsection numbering? I would like something like "1AI".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why do you omit the `subsubsection` level and jump directly down to paragraphs? Also post a compilable document, not only descriptions

Comment: this is an error in your input document, you should use `\subsubsection` not `\paragraph`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is to ensure having `\paragraph`s with all the higher-level sectional units. However, there may be occasions where you want the formatting provided by `\paragraph` without having any `\subsubsection`s within your document.

In order to achieve this deviation from the regular referencing scheme, you need to update the `p`refix `@`ddition for the `paragraph` counter. This prefix is added (in front of the regular counter representation) whenever you set a `\label` for that counter. In many cases, the prefix representation (`\p@<cntr>` for the counter `<cntr>`) is empty, but not with `revtex4`.

The example below updated `\p@paragraph` to remove the `\subsubsection` numbering:

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Roman{paragraph}}

\makeatletter
% Default "parent" label associated with \paragraph:
% \def\p@paragraph{\thesection\,\thesubsection\,\thesubsubsection\,}
\def\p@paragraph{\thesection\,\thesubsection\,}% ...removed \thesubsubsection\,
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See Paragraph~\ref{par:mypar}.

\section{A section}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\paragraph{A paragraph}\label{par:mypar}\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

---

For reference, from the [LaTeX 2e Sources](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **22.1 Environment Counter Macros**; own emphasis added below):

> An environment foo has an associated counter defined by the following control
>   sequences:
>
> `\c@foo`
>   Contains the counter's numerical value. It is defined by `\newcount\foocounter`.
>
> `\thefoo`
>   Macro that expands to the printed value of `\foocounter`. For example, if sections are numbered within chapters, and section headings look like
>
> ```
> Section II-3 The Nature of Counters
> ```
>
> then `\thesection` might be defined by:
>
> ```
> \def\thesection
>    {\@Roman{\c@chapter}-\@arabic{\c@section}}
> ```
>
> `\p@foo`
>   Macro that expands to a printed 'reference prefix' of counter `foo`. **Any `\ref` to a value created by counter `foo` will produce the expansion of `\p@foo\thefoo` when the `\label` command is executed.** See file [`ltxref.dtx`](//mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltxref.dtx) for an extension of this mechanism.
>
> `\cl@foo`
>   List of counters to be reset when foo stepped. Has format `\@elt{countera}\@elt{counterb}\@elt{counterc}`.